# Access Property from Another Class, separate XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

This might be an easy question, but bear with me I am very new and just experimenting. MacOS, Not iOS, let's say I have two separate XIB files (MainMenu.xib and AnotherWindow.xib). I am using the File Menu in MainMenu.xib to open AnotherWindow.xib, and disable the file menu when it opens with:

```
- (IBAction)OpenAnotherWindow:(id)sender {
           if (!anotherWindow) {
               anotherWindow = [[AnotherWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"AnotherWindow"];

       }
           [anotherWindow showWindow:self];
    [self.MenuItem setEnabled:NO];
```

In the AnotherWindow.xib, I want to re-enable the file menu when it closes using:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self.MenuItem setEnabled:YES];
}
```

The problem I have is I am not able to access the MenuItem from the second class because it is part of MainMenu.xib - so I just get error: Property not found on object of type with the [self.MenuItem setEnabled:YES]; in the AnotherWindow.xib

So I guess my question is: How can I access a property like

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *MenuItem;
```

That is in my MainMenu.xib from AnotherWindow.xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually enabling and disabling the menu item, override the function `validateUserInterfaceItem` in the class that contains the `OpenAnotherWindow` IBAction.

The `validateUserInterfaceItem` function takes an item of type `NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem` as an argument. Check if the item's action is `OpenAnotherWindow`. If it is, check if `anotherWindow` is open. If it's open, return false, which will disable the menu item. If the window isn't open, return true, which will enable the menu item. My Objective-C is rusty so I don't have a code listing for you.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer, and it should be marked accepted. One clarification is that `validateUserInterfaceItem` comes from the `NSUserInterfaceValidations` protocol, and adopting that protocol in any class that might be the target of a UI object will give a targeted object a chance to validate the item. Typically, you'd implement `-validateUserInterfaceItem` in responder chain objects like views, view controllers, documents, etc. The OP asks specifically about  menu items, and menu items typically target the first responder, so the responder chain is especially useful there.